# Git log --graph; HEAD to top

Tags: git

When I use

```
git log --graph --all
```

he is showing me always the last commit at the top of the graph.

Is there any option to bring always the HEAD to the top?

Comment: Try `git log --graph --decorate` and see that you *have* HEAD on top.

Comment: Sorry I missed the --all (fixed it in the question) ... and then not the HEAD but the last commit is at top. It is easy to reproduce by jumping to an older branch.

Comment: I don't think it is possible even in specific case where showing HEAD on top wouldn't go against topological (or at least partial topological) order, i.e. no parent comes before all of its children. For example if HEAD is in the middle of linear chain it would be impossible to show it on top.

Answer (score 3):

But the last commit in the current branch *is* where HEAD points to.

Comment: right, but usually I commit something in a branch, then I switch to another branch to do something different. Then the HEAD is far away from my last commit :)

Comment: The poster @Marcel has modified his question. Now he points out that he want HEAD at the top of the graph while using the `--all` option of `git-log`.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you cannot have always HEAD at the top of the graph if you are using `--all`. Your current HEAD can be the child of other commits (in other branches), and in that case it has to be below its parents.