# Display git log --graph --decorate with HEAD on top

Tags: git, git-log

With this command:

```
git log --all -n30 --graph --abbrev-commit --decorate \
   --date=relative --format=format:'%h - (%ar) %s - %an%d'
```

I will get a wonderful tree which is exactly what I am looking for except that the HEAD is not always on the top.

If I remove the `--all` option, I will also lose all the displayed branches.

How can I keep both the HEAD on top and still see the full tree visible up to the last 30 elements?

In other words what I get is

```
   * d4b7d5a - (foo)
   * * 44f53e2 - (HEAD)
   |/
   * 4587f32 - (bar)
```

And What I want to get is:

```
   * 44f53e2 - (HEAD)  <- HEAD on the top
   | * d4b7d5a - (foo)
   |/
   * 4587f32 - (bar)
```

Comment: Would adding HEAD work? `git log --all -n30 ... HEAD`

Comment: It does not seem to. `git log --graph --oneline HEAD foo` and `git log --graph --oneline foo HEAD` show exactly the same thing :-(.

Comment: --all is listing all the branches so of course you will lose them if you remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I dont believe it is possible, since d4b7d5a(foo) commit was made after your HEAD. You could reverse the order of your log but thats not the point. The only way I know to leave HEAD always on top would be something like the option '--before' to display only the commits made before HEAD.

You can find more about --before and others filters here:
https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-log

Any way, you can find a similar question here:
[Git log --graph; HEAD to top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21877121/git-log-graph-head-to-top)

But there is no solution there either.